# Novice haskell - sequential monad binding

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for the idiomatic way to do this. It works, but seems like I must be reinventing something in the standard library. What's the right way to do this?

I'm trying to pass a list of functions and bind them in sequence. Toy example:

```
bindSeq :: (Monad m) => m a ->  [(a -> m a)] -> m a
bindSeq m [] = m 
bindSeq m (x:xs) = bindSeq ( m >>= x ) xs

bindSeq (Just 4) [ Just . (+1), Just . (+2)]
Just 7
```

Comment: What about `bindSeq = foldl' (>>=)`?

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: See [concatM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:concatM) in the **monad-loops** package.

Also, you could define a Monoid instance, like [this](https://gist.github.com/hiratara/4038651). Maybe there is a standard one already defined, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fixnum wrote in 2013, your `bindSeq` is `foldl' (>>=)`

But if you want to see this as an "effectful fold" over values, then you can just "put on m-colored glasses" and overlook the `m`, then look what's left. Absent the monadic effects, you want a signature: `a -> [a -> a] -> a`.

This is folding function application and can be written `foldl (flip ($))`.

So now, "promote" that to be effectful and we see the following:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t foldM (flip ($))
foldM (flip ($)) :: Monad m => a -> [a -> m a] -> m a
```

as desired!